# How to retain the formatting of Apple Notes at export?

Tags: macos, notes.app, formatting

I want to export some notes as PDFs or any other type of text file to save them locally, but when I go to *File -> Export as PDF...* it shrinks down the note page width, meaning the lines of code and my notes look completely different than what I have formatted them to look like.

I am not 100% sure, but if I remember correctly, about 6 months ago I, somehow, managed to retain the width of the note window and its dark background while exporting a note.

How can I export my notes with the correct formatting?

MacOS Monterey / version 12.6 / MacBook Pro 2016

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**Print** > Uncheck  **Rewrap contents to fit page** > **PDF** > Save to desired location

This seems to retain the original formatting. As far as background goes, I doubt it is an option to natively export a dark mode-themed PDF as printing such a page would be a massive waste of ink. You would have to screenshot your note and print the screenshot to save the dark formatting.

Standard screenshot: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The solution I have found in the end is to copy the Apple Note and paste it into a TextEdit file and save it as .rtf.

Answer (score -1):

Did you do it from an iPhone last time? On an iPhone, you can take a screenshot (power + volume up), tap the screenshot, and then you get the option to save the "Full Page."